# Enyo IDE "Ares" Not correctly working

Tags: javascript, enyo

I have installed Ares as it instructs on their Git-hub page. The webpage loads but it give me this screen
http://imgur.com/crGfHkW
If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know what you tried for installation.
(did you install using `npm -d install ares-ide` ?)

And can I know your node version (you can check it using 'node --version') and your system ? (windows 7 ? mac ? )

And I'll appreciate if you do the following. (if you can do `git clone` from ares GitHub.)

1. Recent ares needs node 10.0.x version.
2. git clone with option '--recursive'
3. git submodule update --init --recursive
4. npm install
5. (try to run again)

Please let me know the difference from the previous try.

Comment: I did use the npm -d install ares-ide command. It installed though that and I got the picture I linked too. It will not find my system. I am running windows 7 Professional
The version is v0.10.18